# Web2py Admin Ajax Save Not Working

Tags: web2py

I've been having this problem on and off for a couple of weeks now, and I can't figure out what's causing it. The issue appears to occur after I make changes to a view, and then save those changes using ajax save (<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>).

When ajax save is not working, I notice that pages dedicated to editing views become slightly distorted after the page fully loads (e.g. it looks like height of the navbar and footer increases, and the buttons lose styling), and <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> always brings up a dialog to save the page as an html file on your machine. I also notice that the edit pages initially load quickly (appear to be done loading) with the title 'editing app' in the browser, but then after a second some additional loading occurs, which is then followed by the distortion and a new title in the browser (the title of the actual page).

Has anyone else experienced this issue? I'm running 2.9.12.

-- EDIT

I also should note that when this happened, I was saving multiple views via ajax save, one after another, in a very short period of time. Moreover, I have multiple applications in Web2py and this doesn't seem to extend to other apps running on the same system.

--
Here is a video showing what's going on: https://vid.me/rSMS

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the code editing window has focus (i.e., the cursor is in the editor) before hitting ctrl-s. It sounds like maybe you have clicked somewhere outside the editor, so when you hit ctrl-s, the browser receives the command to save the current HTML page.

Comment: The window may be losing focus, but I can't seem to get the focus back to the frame. I uploaded a video demonstrating the issue; that I've clicked in the frame multiple times with no change in the outcome. Notice the distortion in the buttons at about 4 seconds.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I don't know what could be causing that.

Comment: When I look at the console I see this: app.com/app/appadmin/hooks 404 (NOT FOUND) in admin/static/_2.9.12/js/jquery.js:4. I'm troubleshooting that right now. I don't get that error on other apps. In this app, though, I'm using jquery-2.1.3.min.js.